# Error While trying to enable .NET framework in windows 8.1 enterprise

Tags: windows-8.1, .net-framework-version

Why am I getting error message while I was trying to enable .NET framework in my newly installed windows 8.1 enterprise edition? The error message is

> Error: 14028 A component's file does not match the verification information present in the component manifest.

How can I get ride of this problem?

Comment: Not sure. What have you found while searching for this error online?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\André>err 14028
# for decimal 14028 / hex 0x36cc
  ERROR_SXS_FILE_HASH_MISMATCH                                   winerror.h
# A component's file does not match the verification
# information present in the component manifest.
```

This looks like the files on the DVD/ISO are corrupted. Download the ISO again and check the SHA1 hash that it matches to the value that Microsoft provides.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error too, is was NOT a corrupted file. I tried 3 ISO's from DVD and 3 ISO's from harddisk. Everytime the same error.

I found a nice guy who wrote a Framework 3.5 Offline Installer that works well :

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47748-NET-Framework-3-5-Standalone-Installer-for-Windows-8-1-x86-x64

Comment: May be my ISO file was really corrupted though I don't know why. By the way I solved this problem by downloading .NET form internet and directly installing on my computer.